# Reducing with a bloom filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bloom-filter

I would like to get a fast approximate set membership, based on a String-valued function applied to a large Spark RDD of String Vectors (~1B records). Basically the idea would be to reduce into a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). This bloom filter could then be broadcasted to the workers for further use.

More specifically, I currently have

```
rdd: RDD[Vector[String]]
f: Vector[String] => String
val uniqueVals = rdd.map(f).distinct().collect()
val uv = sc.broadcast(uniqueVals)
```

But `uniqueVals` is too large to be practical, and I would like to replace it with something of smaller (and known) size, i.e. a bloom filter.

My questions:

- is it possible to reduce into a Bloom filter, or do I have to collect first, and then construct it in the driver?
- is there a mature Scala/Java Bloom filter implementation available that would be suitable for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Bloom filters can be reduced, because they have some nice properties (they are [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid)). This means you can do all the aggregation operations in parallel, doing effectively just one pass over the data to construct the BloomFilter for each partition and then reduce those BloomFilters together to get a single BloomFilter that you can query for `contains`.

There are at least two implementations of BloomFilter in Scala and both seem mature projects (haven't actually used them in production). The first one is [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) and the second one is [Twitter's Algebird](https://github.com/twitter/algebird). Both contain implementations of different sketches and a lot more.

This is an example how to do that with Breeze:

```
import breeze.util.BloomFilter

val nums = List(1 to 20: _*).map(_.toString)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(nums, 5)

val bf = rdd.mapPartitions { iter =>
  val bf = BloomFilter.optimallySized[String](10000, 0.001)
  iter.foreach(i => bf += i)
  Iterator(bf)
}.reduce(_ | _)

println(bf.contains("5")) // true
println(bf.contains("31")) // false
```

Comment: One issue with this solution: It sends all the bloom filters for all partitions to the driver before merging them which can easily cause the driver to run out of memory.  `treeReduce(_ | _, depth=DEPTH)` helps with this issue by reducing in a tree-like fashion.

Comment: Great solution. You should also add a coalesce between the map and the reduce for better performance. As there is only one bloom filter by partition, the reduce directly sends all the bloom filters to the driver for the final merge. If there are many partitions, it can be slow or even go OOM. Coalesce with number of partition k such that k*k ~= initial number of partitions will be optimum, even if some executors are not used.